# Só abrir prompt se clicar no elemento pai e não no elemento filho

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma `div` e dentro dela tem vários outros elementos (img, span, etc.). O que preciso fazer é que só quando clicar na `div` pai o `prompt` do javascript abra, caso clique em outro elemento (filho, os que estão dentro) não aconteça nada.

O problema é que quando clico em qualquer elemento que esteja dentro da `div` pai, ele faz a função que dei ao elemento pai, mas estou clicando no elemento filho.

```
$(document).on('click', '.taggd', function (e) {

          let imgWidth  = $("div.taggd").width();
          let imgHeight = $("div.taggd").height();

          let left = Math.floor(((e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) * 100)/imgWidth),
              top  = Math.floor(((e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) * 100)/imgHeight);

          let texto = prompt('O que deseja exibir ?');

          taggd.addTag(
                   Taggd.Tag.createFromObject({
                        position: { x: left/100, y: top/100 },
                        text: texto,
                    }).show()
                   );
      });
```

O **.taggd** é o elemento pai e quando clicado em qualquer lugar dessa div ele tem que fazer essa função que está dentro. Mas dentro dessa div tem outros elementos que terão outras funções, mas sempre que clico no elemento filho, ele está executando o código acima.

Answer (score 1):

Há duas opções:

- **adicionar um `e.stopPropagation();` para impedir que o evento propague.**

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeType == 1 && e.target.classList.contains('taggd')) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('click no pai');
  } else {
    console.log('click no filho');
  }
}, true);
```

```html
<div class="taggd" id="pai">
  Pai
  <p id="filho">Filho</p>
</div>
```

- **comparar `e.target === this`:**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.taggd', function(e) {
  if (e.target == this) console.log('Pai');
  else console.log('Filho');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="taggd" id="pai">
  Pai
  <p id="filho">Filho</p>
</div>
```